# Application on clients machine with database operations called directly from server

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, desktop

I am having trouble phrasing this correctly but is it possible to have a desktop based application where all of the work is done on the server (specifically with the database) instead of the client? The use case is that for an internal application where our server is located, the application works great. However, remote workers that have to use the application really struggle with latency issues over our VPN. Our current solution is to just make it into a web application but the problem with that is we feel we will lose efficiency in the application. Ideally we would create a desktop app in something along the lines of WPF but with all of the work (database connection/calls) not done on the client. It doesn't necessarily have to be Microsoft but that is what we are trying to go with. Does anyone have any insight into how this could be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear on the question.  It's definitely possible, essentially that's what a web browser does. You are really just deciding how you want to implement the user interface.  Then you are deciding how to connect to your server to make it perform operations on behalf of the user interface.  There are many options, SOAP, gRPC, REST, .net remoting...

Comment: Not sure that converting it to a web app wil solve anything; in doing so you go from a client app(the app) calling for small amounts of data(TDS) over a slow network (VPN) to a central server(SQLS), and you'll go to a client app(the browser) calling for large amounts of data(html etc) over a slow network (the internet) to a central server (IIS) that talks to another server (SQLS). Sounds like a regression to me!

Comment: If latency is the issue the problem is making lots of small calls for data. Change your strategy so your apps are less chatty with their back end requests

Comment: @MarkAtRamp51 that is correct. Essentially we are confused on how we would actually do this. As in, with the desktop application it is installed locally with the database connection which is a WPF application. When we install it locally on the users who are remote, it struggles as it has to go over a VPN. Are you saying there are ways to install a desktop application on the client that maintains the performance of having it installed on the server? Like in this example, how would a WPF application maintain the network performance of a web app that is hosted on the server?

Comment: Have you identified where the bottleneck is? Is the traffic getting choked up at the vpn gateway? Is the database returning datasets slowly? Is the latency when connecting to the database? or is the latency occurring when returning data?

Comment: @MarkAtRamp51 I believe it is indeed the VPN gateway. The actual datasets/queries aren't even that large (although the database is). Essentially any returning of the dataset at all is significantly worse on the VPN. For example, something that takes 10 minutes in office might take 8 hours remotely.  And something that takes less than a second in office takes 5 seconds remotely.

Comment: @Dan posted updates below.

Answer (score 1):

@Dan's comment: well it's really hard to diagnose without seeing the application itself.  Since your application is connecting directly to the Database server, the question would be: Is the db server returning large datasets that are being processed by your desktop application; if yes, then moving that logic to a server application that connects to the database to perform the processing and return a result would reduce network latency if that result is smaller than the source data it processed.

However this quickly spirals into other questions. What data processing is being done? Depending on what is happening with the data would change your server side architecture. If it's CPU intensive than it will be important that your server side application can horizontally scale with demand.

All that being said, this is only posted as an answer because it wouldn't fit in a comment.  It's not really an answer, and your question really requires a good architect to sit with you and look at the needs of your users and application to address this fairly.

**UPDATED**

So based on your comments I can't be sure if this is better or worse in your scenario, but you could try VDI solutions or application streaming solutions.  The great thing is that despite whether it works out or not you can test an application streaming solution with no changes to your application.  However depending on your network and security requirements the real work would be getting your systems connected with the application streaming service.

- You could try something like https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/ AWS APPSTREAM, and see if this is any faster for your users.  Above and beyond that you would probably need to get another set of eyes on your solution and architecture to help you redesign/rearchitect the application to work within the constraints you are dealing with.
- Talk to your VPN software vendor to see if you can better scale their solution.
- Configure your VPN to use a split tunnel connection so that all of your users internet traffic doesn't route over your VPN gateway unless that's a requirement for you.